# Align image top right in tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm trying to align an image right next to an ad much like damnyouautocorrect.com does.

I placed the ad code right below the  tag and it pushed the content down as expected.

It hugs the left side. Next, I want to place a Twitter follow button and have it align and hug the right side. The problem is no matter what I do it hugs the left side and stays right below the ad.

I've tried

`margin-left: auto;`
`margin-right: auto;`
`float:right;`

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're going to have post more of your code. Because from the little you've given here, it's just a matter of floating the ad left, and floating the image right, and I'm guessing that you tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
position:absolute;
right:0px;
```

Comment: maybe try 'display:inline;' to display it on same level

Answer (score 0):

The sample link you posted uses a layout based on tables (boo).

So it's hard to say much with the little info you've posted...however, it sounds to me like the problem is that the element hugging the left does not have float:left;

You CANNOT have 2 elements under the same 'horizontal' line, each floated to a different side if one of either is not using the float property. For example

LEFT BLOCK | RIGHT BLOCK

Where leftblock has {float:left;}
Where rightblock has {float:right;}

And, to play it safe, make sure their combined width's do not exceed the parent's width or else the second one will always jump to the next line.

Hope this helps